# how to bind inverse boolean, JavaFX

Tags: java, binding, boolean, javafx-8

My goal is to bind these two properties such as when `checkbox` is selected then `paneWithControls` is enabled and vice-versa.

```
CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox("click me");
Pane paneWithControls = new Pane();

checkbox.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(paneWithControls.disableProperty());
```

with this code however its opposite to what I want. I need something like inverse boolean binding. Is it possible or do I have to make a method to deal with it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you want only a one-way binding, you can use the `not()` method defined in `BooleanProperty`:

```
paneWithControls.disableProperty().bind(checkBox.selectedProperty().not());
```

This is probably what you want, unless you really have other mechanisms for changing the `disableProperty()` that do not involve the `checkBox`. In that case, you need to use two listeners:

```
checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> 
    paneWithControls.setDisable(! isNowSelected));

paneWithControls.disableProperty().addListener((obs, wasDisabled, isNowDisabled) ->
    checkBox.setSelected(! isNowDisabled));
```

Comment: `paneWithControls.disableProperty().bind(checkBox.selectedProperty().not());` this gives me compiller error: _The method bind(BooleanBinding) is undefined for the type ReadOnlyBooleanProperty_

Comment: the other way around: `checkbox.selectedProperty().bind(paneWithControls.disableProperty().not());` gives an exception when I click checkbox `java.lang.RuntimeException: CheckBox.selected : A bound value cannot be set.`

Comment: I think you must have used disabledProperty instead of disableProperty

Comment: how about from FXML? if we had a `CheckBox` with `fx:id=abc` then code like this: `<TextField disable=${abc.selected}/>` will cause the text field to be disabled when the checkbox is checked. How do we get the same behavior when its unchecked?

Answer (score 1):

```
checkbox.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(paneWithControls.disableProperty().not());
```

should work

Answer (score 1):

Using the [EasyBind library](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) one can easily create a new ObservableValue that from `checkbox.selectedProperty()` that has the invert of its values.

```
paneWithControls.disableProperty().bind(EasyBind.map(checkbox.selectedProperty(), Boolean.FALSE::equals));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?
See link below
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/BooleanExpression.html#not--

Comment: ...disableProperty().not()

Comment: but it returns `BooleanBinding` value. I can't use it as in example above.